# TypeError : can't concat str to bytes

Tags: qgis, mac

I'm actually using QGIS (3.10 a Coruña) on Mac OS Catalina and I'm having troubles with it.
I'd like to use the function "r.reclass" but it doesn't run correctly. It says that there is an incompatibility with the code at some lines. I hope my screenshot will help to find how I can get rid of the problem...

I saw that it says that the type error is: `TypeError: can't concat str or bytes`.

[image]

Comment: Can you try to choose another simpler path for the output? I am not mistaken there's a single quotation in your output path. It may cause a confusion.

Comment: It works but it says now : "warning unable to set projection" when I run it, and when I try to save it, it says : "unable to perform zip". Do you know how I can solve this ? Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem must be caused by the letter `é` within path string. Because `'\xe9'` refers to `é` in the error `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' ...`.

Change all letters `é` into `e` in paths, then try again.